# How to add edit and delete link on index.blade.php file in laravel for record?

Tags: php, laravel-5, routes

I want to add the edit and delete link on the index.blade.php file for deleting and edit the records.

Here is my code:

Route file:

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('/patient/emergency-contacts' , 'patient/EmergencyContacts@index'  ) ;
Route::get('/patient/emergency-contacts/create' ,  'patient/EmergencyContacts@create' ) ;
Route::get('/patient/emergency-contacts/{id}/edit', 'EmergencyContactsController@edit' ) ;
Route::post('/patient/emergencycontacts_store', ['uses' => 'EmergencyContactsController@store', 'as' => 'emergencycontacts_store']);
Route::get('/patient/emergencycontacts_delete/{id}','EmergencyContactsController@destroy' ) ;
Route::resource('/patient/emergency-contacts', 'EmergencyContactsController');
```

Index.blade.php : views/patient/emergencycontacts/index.blade.php - Path

```
 @extends('layouts.master')

  @section('content')

          <div id="emer" class="tabcontent">
      <h3>Emergency Contacts</h3>
      @if(Session::has('message')) <div class="alert alert-info"> {{Session::get('message')}} </div> @endif
<ul>
@foreach($result as $error)
    <li><div class="details"><label> Saluation</label><span>{{ $error->salutation }}</span></div>
        <div class="details"><label> First Name</label><span>{{ $error->firstname }}</span></div>
        <div class="details"><label> Last Name</label><span>{{ $error->lastname }}</span></div>
        <div class="details"><label> Relationship</label><span>{{ $error->relationship }}</span></div>
        <div class="details"><label> Phone</label><span>{{ $error->phone }}</span></div>
        <div class="details"><label> Fax</label><span>{{ $error->fax }}</span></div>


     {!! Form::open() !!}
        {!! Form::submit('Edit', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) !!}
        {!! Form::close() !!}</li>
   {!! Form::open() !!}
        {!! Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) !!}
        {!! Form::close() !!}</li>
    @endforeach
  </ul>



   </div>


   @stop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there....

```
 // ASSUMING YOU HAVE THESE 2 ARBITRARY ROUTES ALREADY DEFINED:
 Route::get('/patient/emergency-contacts/{id}/edit', 
            'EmergencyContactsController@edit',
             ['as' => 'emergencycontacts_edit']) ; );

 Route::get('/patient/emergency-contacts/{id}/delete', 
            'EmergencyContactsController@delete', 
             ['as' => 'emergencycontacts_delete']) ;
```

And here the Basic Contents of your Blade Template...

```
  @extends('layouts.master')

  @section('content')

  <div id="emer" class="tabcontent">
      <h3>Emergency Contacts</h3>
      @if(Session::has('message')) 
          <div class="alert alert-info"> 
            {{Session::get('message')}} 
          </div> 
      @endif
   <ul>
  @foreach($result as $error)
      <li>
          <div class="details">
             <label> Saluation</label>
             <span>{{ $error->salutation }}</span>
          </div>
          <div class="details">
            <label> First Name</label>
            <span>{{ $error->firstname }}</span>
          </div>
          <div class="details">
            <label> Last Name</label>
            <span>{{ $error->lastname }}</span>
          </div>
          <div class="details">
             <label> Relationship</label>
             <span>{{ $error->relationship }}</span>
         </div>
         <div class="details">
            <label> Phone</label>
            <span>{{ $error->phone }}</span> 
         </div>
         <div class="details">
            <label> Fax</label>
            <span>{{ $error->fax }}</span>
         </div>
```

Here is where you do things a little differently:

```
         <!-- ••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••• -->
         <!-- ••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••• -->

         <!-- ADD THE EDIT + DELETE LINKS USING NORMAL <A /> TAGS -->
         <!-- & HREF TARGETING THE EDIT/DELETE LINKS RESPECTIVELY.-->
         <!-- WHY USE A FORM? YOU JUST WANTED TO EITHER UPDATE OR -->
         <!-- DELETE A RECORD WITH A SPECIFIC ID.... A LINK WILL DO -->
         <!-- SURE; YOU'D NEED A FORM FOR THE UPDATE/EDIT PROCESS   -->
         <div class="actions">
           <!-- HERE; YOU NEED A WAY TO OBTAIN THE contact_id -->
           <!-- AGAIN WE PRESUME IT'S ACCESSIBLE VIA:         -->
           <!-- $error->contactId                             -->
           <!-- YOU (AS THE PROGRAMMER) KNOW THIS BEST...     -->

           <a href="{{ route('emergencycontacts_edit', ['id' => 
                       $error->contactId]) }}" 
                       class="btn btn-success" >
                 <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit
           </a>
         </div>
         <div class="actions">
           <a href="{{ route('emergencycontacts_delete', ['id' =>
                       $error->contactId]) }}" 
                       class="btn btn-danger" > 
                  <i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete
           </a>
         </div>
    </li>

@endforeach
```